# Why does adding a new element to an array list replace all the previous elements with the new one?

Tags: java

I have a method in my class `TextPlan`, which calls all my rules in another class `RSTRule` and adds all rules to an array list. For this method I have used `import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and`import java.lang.reflect.Method`.
But it adds to the array list incorrectly. For example, the result of`add(RSTRule)` in each call of RST methods are as follows:

```
 call 1: RSTRules.add(RSTRule)=R1
 call 2: RSTRules.add(RSTRule)=R2,R2
 call 3: RSTRules.add(RSTRule)=R3,R3,R3
 call 4: RSTRules.add(RSTRule)=R4,R4,R4
```

That means that every time I add a new element, it removes the previous elements from the array list, but repeats the new element.

Here is my code:

```
public class TextPlan extends ArrayList<Object>  {

  RSTRules rstRules=new RSTRules();

  public RSTRules produceAllRSTRules(RSTRules rstRules) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    RSTRule rstRule=new RSTRule();
        Method[] methods =rstRule.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
             if (method.getName().startsWith("generate")) {
            rstRule=(RSTRule)method.invoke(rstRule);
            rstRules.add(rstRule) ;
               }
         }
          return rstRules;
   }
}
```

hier one of my methodes in "RSTRule", which i call all of them in "TextPlan" to produce an instance of all Rules;

```
public class RSTRule{
    protected String ruleName;
    protected DiscourseRelation discourseRelation;
    protected String ruleNucleus;
    protected String ruleSatellite;
    protected String condition;
    int heuristic;


    public RSTRule generateBothAppearBothCosts_Join(){
            this.discourseRelation=DiscourseRelation.Join;
            this.ruleNucleus="BothProductAppear_Elaboration";
            this.ruleSatellite="BothProductCost_Elaboration";
            this.ruleName="BothProductAppearAndBothProductCost_Join";
            this.condition=null;
            this.heuristic=9;
            return this;
        }
}
```

Comment: Man, please rephrase you question. Unable to understand what you wrote :)

Comment: Show us the `generate***` methods of your `rstRule.getClass()` class. Is it creating new instance?

Comment: You need to check the method you are invoking reflectively... It's probably got something to do with that method rather than reflection.

Comment: Haven't read the question, just the title, and first thing that comes to mind is that you keep adding references to the same mutable object. So each time you change that object, the change is visible on all items in your list (because they all refer to that same object)...

Comment: Why are you declaring this list RSTRules rstRules=new RSTRules(); and you're not using it? And why you're creating the object to "analyze" inside the producer method (RSTRule rstRule=new RSTRule();)?

Comment: but i have to declare RSTRuel in producer method, because for example in this row: Method[] methods =rstRule.getClass().getMethods(); I call the methodes of RSTRule with an instance of that

Answer (score 5):

You're not adding four new `RSTRule` instances to the list, you're adding the same `RSTRule` instance four times and modifying it each time through. Since it's the same instance stored four times, the modifications show up in every position of the list.

Comment: you mean, I should creat a new RSTRule in each method, which i call them RSTRule rst=new RSTRule();

Comment: But rstRule=(RSTRule)method.invoke(rstRule); ovverrides the rstRule pointer only, not the one stored in the arraylist.

Comment: can you give me a correct code for this rstRule=(RSTRule)method.invoke(rstRule);  please, realy i do not know what should i change

Comment: Thank you for all comments and answers, i have found it,